# Create Folder on Home Screen where i can put some icons in grid

Tags: android, directory, android-appwidget, android-livefolders

In Android I want to make folder on home screen programmatically like **clean master**  do for game booster OR  [MyJio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jio.myjio&hl=en) app put its all applications in one folder. I try with Live folder but its deprecated and also not working for me in latest android version.
Is it a widget or what i can't understand about this please help me to understand this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hay did you get your answer?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with dialog, Create app icon with multiple app image and set it as your app icon, Now Create one activity and register it in manifest like
, i have only display two button you can add more in your dialog layout

```
    <activity android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now your activity as follow

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {

AlertDialog dialog;
LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
    mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked OK button
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}}
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/test"
android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something similar like this [Assistive Touch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easytouch.assistivetouch&hl=en), a floating button which will be available on top of all app or wants to create simple folder 
which is accessible on home screen only?

Comment: I want to create folder on Home screen programatically and want to show icons on that folder and also icons should be clickable